# App to app authentication with Windows Authentication taking 10 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, .net-core

We are doing http calls with Windows Authentication between asp.net apps (specifically a .net core an and a standard .net framework 4.5.1 app) apps using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials });
var response= await _winHttpClient.GetAsync(url);
...
```

This works fine, except for that the first request takes 10 seconds. The requests then go fast for about 40 seconds, and then one request takes 10 seconds. This cycle goes on forever.

Looking at the IIS logs on the receiving end, we can se that every request is denied (401) and then a follow up request goes through, and every so often the delay between these are about 10s. This is all invisible to the client code - it is worked out by the underlying framework.

Example:

```
2017-03-17 14:19:40 10.241.108.23 GET /person/search/john - 80 - 10.211.37.246 - 401 2 5 31
2017-03-17 14:19:40 10.241.108.23 GET /person/search/john - 80 utv\frank 10.211.37.246 - 200 0 0 93
2017-03-17 14:19:41 10.241.108.23 GET /person/search/johnn - 80 - 10.211.37.246 - 401 2 5 46
2017-03-17 14:19:51 10.241.108.23 GET /person/search/johnn - 80 utv\frank 10.211.37.246 - 200 0 0 281
```

It seems as if the credentials are somehow cached, and have to be refreshed every 40ish seconds.

It is worth noting that this problem doesn't occur when both applications are run locally, only when they are run in the actual hosting environment.

What's going on?
Is it expected behaviour that the consumer has to do two calls for every request? And why do some of the requests take 10 seconds to authenticate?

Any help would be appreciated.